# Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'public/community_updates/1621342668954index.jpg']

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, multer

I am trying to upload file but getting error i don't know why but it is adding filename in destination path so that's why it is giving error but i know reason behind it why it is taking filename too in path

```
    var communityStorage = multer.diskStorage({
        destination : function(req,file,cb) {
            
            cb(null,'./public/community_updates/')
        },
        filename : function(req,file,cb) {
            
            let fileName = Date.now()+file.originalname;
            cb(null, fileName)
            
        }
    });
```

This is my multer function

```
    let uploadFile = commUpload.any('files')
                uploadFile(req,res, async(err)=>{
                    if(err){
                         console.log(err);
                    res.status(400).json({message : enums.SERVER_ERROR, data : err})
                    }
                    else {
                        let url = '';
                        console.log(req.files)
                        if(req.files)  {
                            url = webUrl + 'community_updates/'+ req.files[0].filename
                        }
                        
                        let data = {
                            title : req.body.title,
                            img : url,
                            links : req.body.links,
                            description : req.body.description
                        }
                        let saveData = await saveUser(updateModel,data)
                        
                        res.status(200).json({success : true, data : enums.ADD_UPDATE})
                    }
                });
```

Comment: Just try this,  url = './'+webUrl + 'community_updates/'+ req.files[0].filename

Comment: No this will not work even this section of the code is not running @NithinKJoy

Comment: can you show me the full error log?